# Aurelia and easel-js : Stage() is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, aurelia, createjs, easeljs

Trying to include easel-js as a vendor library to an Aurelia application.  I'm new to ESNext and module systems, and I'm getting a confusing error - just right at the top of interacting with easel-js by newing a stage from app.js or any component js file I get **"Unhandled rejection type error: Stage is not a constructor."**

Here is the line of code in my component, which is invoked after dom attached.

```
this.stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasName");
```

I initially had this working directly in app.js by hacking the easel-js script tag into the index.html file.  I could new a stage and draw shapes all in that one file, no problem. I knew that wasn't going to be right way, I want to divide up the easel-js interactions into various classes, so read up on including third party javascript libraries as dependencies in Aurelia and performed the following:

I performed an npm install of easel-js in my project directory, examined the directory in node_modules thus created.  In the lib directory of easel-js I found minified js version, which is same version I was manually including previously (0.8.2).  I edited Aurelia.json to add dependency as follows:

"dependencies": [
      "easel-js",
      "aurelia-binding",

Then I moved above code to another ES6 class, invoked from app.js, and included an import.

```
import * as createjs from "../../scripts/vendor-bundle";
```

And voila, what was working the hacky way now throws "not a constructor" when I try to new an easel-js Stage.

One thing I notice is that in the lib directory of easel-js under node_modules, there are a number of js files:

```
README.md           easeljs-NEXT.combined.js    webgl-0.8.2.min.js
easeljs-0.8.2.combined.js   easeljs-NEXT.min.js     webgl-NEXT.combined.js
easeljs-0.8.2.min.js        webgl-0.8.2.combined.js     webgl-NEXT.min.js
```

I'm also not sure what the differences are between them.  The easel-js library I was manually including and getting to work from app.js was the 0.8.2.min.js from their website.  When I examine Aurelia's vendor-bundle.js file for my project, it looks like it is pulling in that same file that worked for me the hacky way.

```
    function _aureliaConfigureModuleLoader(
{requirejs.config({"baseUrl":"src/",
"paths":{"aurelia-dependency-injection":"../node_modules/aurelia-dependency-injection/dist/amd/aurelia-dependency-injection",
"easel-js":"../node_modules/easel-js/lib/easeljs-0.8.2.min",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem with angular2 (typescript). Did you find a solution??

Comment: Nope - no solution yet.  I'm still in early stages of development, and the require javascript error caused by manually including it as a non-npm lib doesn't prevent createjs from functioning.  Intersection of Aurelia/Angular and CreateJS is pretty small ;-).  If you figure it first let me know!

Comment: I found my solution, which is highly angular-cli specific. I had to add the references into the .angular-cli.json under the "scripts" array:

`"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/createjs-easeljs/lib/easeljs-NEXT.combined.js",
        "../node_modules/createjs-tweenjs/lib/tweenjs-NEXT.combined.js",
        "../node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js"
       ],`

Does that help???

Comment: I think I will have similar solution - Aurelia allows third party non-npm libs to be added in a json file, which gulp then uses as part of their build process - I suspect that is what I will end up with.  I'll post Aurelia specific solution here when I get back to wresting with it.  The CLIs are nice, but it's a magic box - when something doesn't work you suddenly have to open the box and figure things out....

Comment: I should do the same for angularjs... I saw a related post